# git-svn clone: unable to connect to a repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

Environment information

```
~$ git --version
git version 2.11.0
~$ git svn --version
git-svn version 2.11.0 (svn 1.9.5)
~$ svn --version
svn, version 1.9.5 (r1770682)
```

I'm attempting to clone an internally-hosted SVN repository, but I'm met with the following error:

```
~$ git svn clone http://[server]/svn/dev1
Initialized empty Git repository in [~]/test/[root]/.git/
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL \
  'http://[server]/svn/[root]' at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

SVN checkout works as expected.  I've tried using the `svn://` protocol, but then it does not recognize `[server]` as a known hostname.

If I separate `clone` into `init` and `fetch`, it's the `fetch` step that is failing.

I should add that solutions like SmartGit are sadly not an option for me; I work at a company with >1000 devs so the cost to support one developer would be astronomical.

---

`SVN.pm:148` reads `my $ra = Git::SVN::Ra->new($url);` – from elsewhere in my research (I can't find the post anymore), I believe this is a wrapper around an SVN function.  Here's the definition of `Ra->new`:

```perl
sub new {
        my ($class, $url) = @_;
        $url = canonicalize_url($url);
        return $RA if ($RA && $RA->url eq $url);

        ::_req_svn();

        $RA = undef;
        my ($config, $baton, $callbacks) = prepare_config_once();
        my $self = SVN::Ra->new(url => $url, auth => $baton,
                              config => $config,
                              pool => SVN::Pool->new,
                              auth_provider_callbacks => $callbacks);
        $RA = bless $self, $class;

        # Make sure its canonicalized
        $self->url($url);
        $self->{svn_path} = $url;
        $self->{repos_root} = $self->get_repos_root;
        $self->{svn_path} =~ s#^\Q$self->{repos_root}\E(/|$)##;
        $self->{cache} = { check_path => { r => 0, data => {} },
                           get_dir => { r => 0, data => {} } };

        return $RA;
}
```

I don't know Perl, so this is about as far as I can go on my own – I can't find the `SVN::Ra->new` this mentions.

Comment: Have you dried a few variations on the URL? Maybe it doesn't need the `/dev1` bit.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the idea! I did try a few variations on the URL to no effect, but the resolution for me was sillier :-) See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this 'machine' (Debian under WSL) wasn't able to access `[server]` at all (even though Windows could).  The error message given may not have been very specific, but it was still accurate: git-svn wasn't able to reach a repository at the given URL because it wasn't able to reach the URL at all!

Fully qualifying it as `[server].[company].com` worked for me. Instead of

```
git svn clone http://[server]/svn/dev1
```

I used

```
git svn clone http://[server].[company].com/svn/dev1
```

Comment: The same problem can arise when cloning has worked earlier (e.g., because an older version of git-svn was used) when calling `git svn rebase` but with a slightly different error message: `Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://<url>': Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 717`. There seems to be a bug in Debian Buster's git-svn that wasnt there in Stretch :/

Comment: It's not a bug but a feature: Debian Buster does no longer support TLS <= 1.1 for obvious reasons. When the server does not support at least TLS 1.2 you will end up with the same problems as mentioned above (no matter if you use git-svn or svn directly). A possible workaround is to lower the requirement in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` (`MinProtocol = TLSv1.0`) but the correct fix is to update the server of course.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the http prefix to svn and using an ip adress was the solution for me. Instead of:

```
git svn clone http://[server]/svn/dev1
```

i used:

```
git svn clone svn://[ip adress]/svn/dev1
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `https://your.svn.server/repo` and the error indicates something like  `SSL communication at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line #number#` you should configure `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` as below:

*in first lines of file out of any block:*

`openssl_conf = default_conf`

*at the end of the file or anywhere:*

```
    [default_conf] 
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
    [ssl_sect] 
system_default = system_default_sect
    [system_default_sect]
    #MinProtocol = TLSv1.2 
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```