# Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxxxxxx' at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148

Tags: svn, git-svn

I have been able to download and migrate a SVN repository to gitlab, but I have faced a problem when trying to do the same with another repository located in other location(different url), because the "fit svn fetch" command answer with:

Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxxxxxx' at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.

And the strange thing is that the only one thing that changes between this repository and the other that worked is the URL. In the first repository (the one which worked) after executing the "git svn fetch" command I was requested to introduce a user and password (only the first time) but for the second repository with different URL it doesn't, so I hope someone have faced this issue before and can tell me how to proceed with that, I will appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have at least to try to connect from *pure SVN* to this repo, it can be unreachable from you for a lot of reasons

Answer (score 1):

The error message from your question usually means that the SVN repository is unreachable (offline or the URL is invalid of has typos).

1. Ensure that the SVN repository is online and accessible using the `svn info https://example.url/MyRepo` command.
2. Check answers to similar questions. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/54330287/761095.