git svn clone: "Access forbidden"
I try to clone an SVN repo, but get an error
git svn clone http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common -s -r 10:HEAD
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/some-project/.git/
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common': 
Access to '/svn/<name of the project>/java/common' forbidden at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 310. 

These are lines 309-311 of the SVN.pm file (line 310 is in the middle)
    } elsif ($_minimize_url) {
        my $min_url = Git::SVN::Ra->new($url)->minimize_url;
        $existing = find_existing_remote($min_url, $r);

Here's what I get if I try to execute svn co
svn co http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common 
Username: zolotarevsa                                                                                                              
Password for 'zolotarevsa': **************                                                                                         
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common'                             
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/<name of the project>/java/common' forbidden  

svn info, with a truncated argument (suggested in the comments)
svn info http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn                                                                  
Authentication realm: <http://10.0.0.1:83> SVN Server Login                                                                        
Password for 'zolotarevsa': **************                                                                                         
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://10.0.0.1:83/svn'                                                    
svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn' 

What should I do to successfully perform the cloning? Did I just jump the gun a bit, do I simply not have the necessary permissions yet (it's my first day on the job)?

I think you will need to install svn in the host so that you can check that you can connect to the repository through svn..... my hunch is that you won't and that explains why git can't either.

@eftshift0 thank you! Can you please give me a hint on how you check whether you can connect to an SVN server with regular svn?

Try running a simple command against the svn server, like svn ls url-to-project-in-svn-repo

Would be interesting to see more of the URL part. Especially, where does some-project come from? I'd expect a URL like https://example.com/svn/some-project/trunk (with the trunk part being optional, depending on the repo layout)

"…how you check whether you can connect to an SVN server with regular svn?" https://stackoverflow.com/a/74206344/7976758 svn info http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/ Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+%22Can%27t+create+session%22

@Friedrich I edited the question. It's likely I don't have the permissions yet (the lead is busy, but I want to dive right in)

I already noticed this is turning into an interactive debugging session. What about trying https and giving an explicit --username as documented?

@Friedrich the same "forbidden" message

Might be the permissions after all. Is there any pointer on how you would connect via svn or are you blindly guessing? It's awfully hard to connect to anything if you don't know the URL.

@Friedrich the lead sent me the http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common URL

I wish I wrote a single line of code today, but it seems it's not going to happen ((

@Friedrich it seems it was a permission issue. I executed git svn clone once more and now got: This may take a while on large repositories. Checked through r610. And it froze. I wonder whether anything is happening right now

It seems it was a permission issue. I executed git svn clone once more and now got:
Using higher level of URL: http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>/java/common => http://<IP-address of the host>:<port>/svn/<name of the project>                                          
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 110, path '/java/common'           
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.                                                       
This may take a while on large repositories                                                                                                             
Checked through r610

And then it froze. I'm not sure whether it takes so long to clone 10 commits or -r didn't work for some reason

It takes a long time to run, in my experience..... unless you are dealing with a small repo.... but if it's a long history with multitude or branches and so on, better relax.

I would assume -r 10:HEAD to checkout and convert everything from Subversion's revision 10 to the most recent one. Or, in other words, you're converting everything.

@Friedrich are you sure? What if I don't know the total number of commits but am only interested in the 10 most recent commits?

@eftshift0 will it be finished in 8 hours? What's you bet?

"are you sure?" - what does it matter? You are running the experiment and will be able to tell with certainty in 8 (or 28 - who knows?) hours. In Subversion, each commit creates a revision and you can query the number of revisions with svn info REPO_URL.
