# clone repo from SVN to GIT: unable to connect to a repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm attempting to clone an internally-hosted SVN repository, but I'm met with the following error:

trying

```
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk='trunk' https://*****/svn/****** --non-interactive --trust-server-cert
```

getting

```
Unknown option: non-interactive
Unknown option: trust-server-cert
```

tried

```
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk='trunk' https://*****/svn/******
```

getting

```
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://*********/svn/*********': Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 310.
```

used below URL for reference
http://www.netinstructions.com/a-slow-migration-to-git-from-svn/

Comment: Can you use svn from there? Also, single dash for options? Perhaps double-dash?

Comment: I do not see that either one of the options you are listing there as Unknown are defined for `git-svn`, with single or double-dash. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn Where did you get them?

Comment: Both `--non-interactive` and `--trust-server-cert` are options to the `svn` CLI. There's no reason to imagine they would work with `git svn`. While both `svn` and `git svn` implement the same protocol for communication, they are different applications.

Comment: if I use svn it will not work with my concern since I am maigrating my code from svn to git

Comment: double dash is mandatory base on documentations shared

Comment: I guess what eftshift0 meant was to test whether you can reach your repo with `svn`. This would rule out errors with repo and network. If that's okay, proceed with `git svn`. Also, to what "documentations shared" do you refer? Please [edit] your question and add a hyperlink to clarify. Out of paranoia, I'd quote the prefix as in `--prefix='svn/'` though I don't think that's related to your error.

Comment: I have added the reference

Comment: I tried use many reference but without solutions

Comment: Browsing [possible duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D%5Bsvn%5Dunable+to+connect+to+a+repository), it seems their common root cause was connection issues. [Subversion to Git migration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79165/796259) has also been asked to death on this site. Follow these instructions rather than those of a guy who solves his problems with RHEL by using a Windows machine.

Comment: I know it is a connection issue

Comment: and there is no rules put from my side related to  network

Comment: I don't see how anybody on this site could figure out these network issues. I'm voting to close as duplicate of [git-svn clone: unable to connect to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277632/git-svn-clone-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository)

Comment: any of these answers solve my issue